# buildroot - how to change kernel version string

Tags: linux-kernel, release, buildroot

I work on SAM9G25 EK board with buildroot and Armstrong linux (Linux4sam).
My script is creating linux version "2.6.39+" and this "+" is confusing (/lib/modules folder etc.). I want to remove it. I found only two files .uImage.cmd, and kernel.release that contains this string, but both are generated.

Where is this string created ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a `.config`? Look in there for the value assigned to `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION`.

To have no local version specifed in the kernel's release, either remove `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION` or comment it out by starting the line containing it by a `#`.

The default shall be:

```
#CONFIG_LOCALVERSION is not set
```

Comment: Unfortunately CONFIG_LOCALVERSION=""
#CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO is not set

Comment: Change `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION=""` to `#CONFIG_LOCALVERSION is not set`. @Bartlomiej Grzeskowiak

Answer (score 1):

In this case the main reason was :
scripts/setlocalversion line >170:

```
# append a plus sign if the repository is not in a clean
# annotated or signed tagged state (as git describe only
# looks at signed or annotated tags - git tag -a/-s) and
# LOCALVERSION= is not specified
if test "${LOCALVERSION+set}" != "set"; then
    scm=$(scm_version --short)
    res="$res${scm:++}"
fi
```

I commented this part out.

Comment: So you are pretending to be 2.6.39 when you are not.

Comment: So setting LOCALVERSION before running make (ie: export LOCALVERSION="") would accomplish the same thing. From the script, "touch .scmversion" would also work.