# How can the AOSP build number be customized?

Tags: android, build-process, versioning, android-source, build-numbers

I am building AOSP, v4.4.2. I want to specify a part of the "Build number" string (as per Settings -> About tablet).

[image: About tablet page]

I know that this [can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910969/buildroot-how-to-change-kernel-version-string/12911476#12911476) for the Kernel by using the `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION` defconfig value. But I want to change "Build number", not "Kernel version" (which I was able to do successfully).

Currently, the pertinent parts of my AOSP build are like this:

```
# Source build variables
. build/envsetup.sh

# Specify the build target:
# * user -> limited access; suited for production (no ADB)
# * userdebug -> like "user" but with root access and debuggability; preferred for debugging
# * eng -> development configuration with additional debugging tools (with ADB)
lunch mydevice-eng

# Build it!
time m 2>&1 | tee build.out
```

What should I change to specify the build number?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Makefile is what defines how the build number is created (concatenated) for a build.

---

### user builds

For [user builds](https://source.android.com/source/building-running.html) (build target, as specified with lunch), the build number will simply be "`$(BUILD_ID) $(BUILD_KEYS)`", except if the `DISPLAY_BUILD_NUMBER` parameter is set to “true”.

### eng/userdebug builds

For other builds (i.e. eng/userdebug), much more info is included:

```
build_desc := $(TARGET_PRODUCT)-$(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT) $(PLATFORM_VERSION) $(BUILD_ID) $(BUILD_NUMBER) $(BUILD_VERSION_TAGS)
```

The Makefile source is available here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/android-4.4.2_r1/core/Makefile#106

---

### Setting build parameters in a make file

As [mentioned by @eldarerathis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28180656/3063884), the `BUILD_ID` value in `build/core/build_id.mk` is where part of the build string is defined, however this might be overridden in another make (`*.mk`) file.

When running `lunch`, the value of the `BUILD_ID` will be printed for verification. If this value is different to that found in the `build_id.mk` file, then search for where it’s being set, and re-configure it. For example, if as part of `lunch`, the output includes “4.4.2_1.0.0-ga”:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.4.2
...
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=4.4.2_1.0.0-ga
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
```

...then search for “4.4.2_1.0.0-ga” to find it:

```
me@mybox:~/AOSP$find . -name "*.mk" | xargs grep  "4.4.2_1.0.0-ga"
```

Then, update the `.mk` file that contains the `BUILD_ID`. Set other build parameters accordingly.

`BUILD_NUMBER`, `PLATFORM_VERSION` and `BUILD_ID` are located in: [`build/core/version_defaults.mk`](https://github.com/android/platform_build/blob/kitkat-mr1-release/core/version_defaults.mk#L39). The values are only set if the build is initiated without them set.

### Setting build parameters as a parameter at build time

Alternatively (and in my view preferably), these parameters can be set as part of the build command line like this:

```
me@mybox:~/AOSP$ time m BUILD_ID="MyBuildv1.2" BUILD_NUMBER=12345   2>&1 | tee build.out
```

Answer (score 12):

The `BUILD_ID` value in [`build/core/build_id.mk`](https://github.com/android/platform_build/blob/kitkat-mr1-release/core/build_id.mk) is where this is defined:

```
# BUILD_ID is usually used to specify the branch name
# (like "MAIN") or a branch name and a release candidate
# (like "CRB01").  It must be a single word, and is
# capitalized by convention.

export BUILD_ID=KOT49H
```

That value gets written to your build's properties, and Settings reads it from there, so you simply need to change that one `export` to whatever you want. The comment is merely informational, you need not follow the conventions outlined there. In the master branch they have it defined as `AOSP` currently.

Another available flag is `DISPLAY_BUILD_NUMBER` ([example](https://github.com/android/platform_build/blob/jb-dev/core/build_id.mk)). It's optional, and probably not needed in your situation, but here is a description of how it works, in case it might be of use:

```
# DISPLAY_BUILD_NUMBER should only be set for development branches,
# If set, the BUILD_NUMBER (cl) is appended to the BUILD_ID for
# a more descriptive BUILD_ID_DISPLAY, otherwise BUILD_ID_DISPLAY
# is the same as BUILD_ID
DISPLAY_BUILD_NUMBER := true
```

Comment: Thanks; this looks promising. When I re-do `lunch mydevice-eng` after modifying `build/core/build_id.mk`, I still have the following printed-out: `BUILD_ID=4.4.2_1.0.0-ga`. Does this matter? (I didn't let the full build run)

Comment: I've honestly not seen `lunch` output anything like that. I see it echo exactly what I've defined in `build_id.mk`. Is that the build number you ordinarily see in your settings after you flash a build?

Comment: I've worked it out, and will post the full details soon. You've certainly put me on the right path, so thanks (+1). Basically there's a manufacturer-specific make file that's setting it after it gets set in `build_id.mk`

Comment: Ah, so it was something in the device tree that was overriding it? Is this a non-Nexus device? Might explain why I had not seen that.