# How to change kernel version string with Buildroot

Tags: buildroot

Is there some way in Buildroot to change the kernel version string displayed with the "uname -a" command?  For example:

```
# uname -a
Linux buildroot 5.1.0 #1 PREEMPT Wed Nov 6 13:10:04 MST 2019 armv5tejl GNU/Linux
```

I would like to append something so the version look like: "5.1.0-xxxx-xx".

I check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910969/buildroot-how-to-change-kernel-version-string) post but it doesn't make sense to me.  Which .config file does it refer to?  I see 4 in my Buildroot directory, the default one at the root and three more under "./output", which come from other repos.

Thanks,
Dave.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `LOCALVERSION` configuration parameter of the Linux kernel (the kernel version string is a kernel feature, not a Buildroot feature).

1. from Buildroot enter the Linux configuration interface: `make linux-menuconfig`
2. Go in `General setup` and set `Local version - append to kernel release`
   to `-foo-bar`
3. Exit menuconfig saving your changes
4. Build the whole Buildroot image: `make`

Now `uname -a` will show:
`Linux buildroot 5.1.0-foo-bar #1 PREEMPT Wed Nov 6 13:10:04 MST 2019 armv5tejl GNU/Linux`.

To know how to make these changes persistent, read ["Storing the configuration of other components"](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#customize-store-package-config) in the Buildroot user manual.

Comment: Can you explain how the  BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE and BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_CUSTOM_CONFIG variables work?  Do they need to be used together? It seem I cant set the former without first setting the latter. I find the documentation a little confusing because it says I can "directly specify this file in the Buildroot configuration, using BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_CUSTOM_CONFIG" but that variable only takes "Y/N" value.

Comment: When you set the `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_CUSTOM_CONFIG` variable to `y`, the `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE` option will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Arnout was kind enough to give me steps and pointers to the information I needed to figure this out but for completeness, I'll list all the steps I did to make this happen. I used Buildroots "make xconfig" to set the BR_* variables:

1. Set BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_USE_CUSTOM_CONFIG=y
2. As recommended in [Recommended Directory Structure](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#customize-dir-structure),I created a 
   <BR_ROOT>/board/<company>/<board-name> directory and created an empty linux.config file in that directory.
3. Set BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE equal to the path in Step 2
   i.e BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE=board/<company>/<board-name>/linux.config
4. Executed the command "make linux-update-defconfig" to store my Linux configuration in the file I created in Step 3.
5. Followed the steps Arnout listed in his response to my original question.
6. Rebuilt my kernel and rootfs with "make".

Once I verified that everything was correct, I saved my new configuration with "make savedefconfig".